# Unreal Tournament 99 (GOTY) - Setup.exe won't run on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, unreal-tournament-99

I am trying to install Unreal Tournament 99 (Game of The Year edition) on a Windows 7 computer - I have both CD1 & CD2, however the CD1 setup.exe doesn't run. I've tried everything from running the file as Administrator - changing the Compatibility to older versions of Windows but it never actually executes anything.

I already have UT on my Steam account but want to play a colleague in the office (who hasn't already bought this via Steam) hence why I am trying to install the game outside of Steam with the CD.

Anyone got any ideas on how to fix this or even get hold of the setup.exe file from somewhere (legally)?

Comment: Have you tried disabling UAC?

Comment: What is the condition of the CD itself?  According to this http://www.ut99.org/viewtopic.php?t=373 very nice and detailed post, there is nothing special required to install it from the disc (AKA get it off the disc onto a Windows 7 system).  It could also be the optical drive you are using as well.

Comment: Shouldn't the Steam version be compatible given you've both got the latest/same version? Or did they introduce some changes like Steamworks? Can't check myself, games like UT are too violent to be shown to me on Steam. :(

Answer (score 1):

Had to get another copy of the installer - this worked

Answer (score 0):

Attempt to install the game via [DOSBOX](http://www.dosbox.com/). Apparently it can run the game so it should be able to run the installer. Though I have no solid proof as to whether or not it does. If your co-worker is willing to run a virtual box of linux however, [WINE](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=124&iTestingId=75223) plays it smoothly from what I've read.

Comment: You could maybe get it running via DosBOX if you were willing to torture yourself getting Windows 95 running in DosBOX first. And even then UT would not run properly in it.

Comment: Unreal Tournament (99) is not a DOS game. And it can run naively on Linux, so no need for WINE.

Comment: @Qtax Reiteration of Facts Not Required, but thanks for the input.